# Alert when closing as a dupe favoring a younger question

Tags: feature-request, voting, duplicate-questions

One of my questions was marked as a duplicate today by somebody - rightfully so, too; it was.  The only thing is I asked my question in mid-July, and the duplicate was asked today.  Should there be some type of alert that informs users when they're closing a question as a dupe, and favoring a younger question?

Comment: similar issue, (merging, not closing): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/closing-an-earlier-post-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later-one

Comment: Unless the younger question is by Jon Skeet. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9277#9277

Comment: The problem also happens in reverse: an antiquated question is preferred over a more current one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139619/check-that-an-email-address-is-valid-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... there are visible timestamps on both questions. And the question # that you have to type in will look suspiciously large compared to the one in the address bar. If someone is already ignoring both of those, i'm not sure slapping them in the face with another alert will do much good.

FWIW, sometimes closing the earlier question is the right thing to do - there are plenty of poorly-asked questions laying around. In these instances, i've sometimes flagged for administrator review, and requested a merge - if there are good answers on the older question, this may be appropriate.

Comment: "And the question # that you have to type in will look suspiciously large compared to the one in the address bar" - good point.  A pretty simple `>` test would do the trick, I guess.

Comment: I like the merge idea.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue to consider is that sometimes, depending on sheer luck, the younger question has more and better answers than the older question.

People should use common sense when marking dupes.