# What if the duplicate is better than the original?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733400/why-stacktrace-is-modified-when-you-use-throw-in-c) got closed as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217616/incorrect-stacktrace-by-rethrow).  The later question is both better worded (also has more votes) and better answers (more votes, and a workaround that's not in the original.)

Shouldn't there be an option to close an older question as an inferior duplicate of a newer question?

Or does the long-tail answer always have to be the older inferior question?

Comment: I love that this question itself was a duplicate :)

Comment: @DanM If you follow it, that one is a dup, as well as the one it links to, and finally the fourth one is the non-dup. Talk about a Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 11):

Ideally, close the original as the duplicate of the new one.

In this case flag one of the questions for moderator attention explaining why you think the closing was the wrong way round and they should be able to sort it out.

Comment: That's just not going to happen.  Old questions are dead.  They don't get enough duplicate votes to "beat" newer questions.

Comment: @Andomar - which is why you should flag the question. Mods can overrule the vote.

Comment: @ChrisF do I get notified if the moderator take action on my flag?

Comment: @gsharp - no, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

[Jeff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/closing-an-earlier-post-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later-one/1388#1388):

> Just merge them.