# Show my own entry on top when I visit the elections primary page

Tags: feature-request, election

It would be nice if my own entry during the *Primary* phase of the election was always shown on top. After voting on other candidates, you'll most likely be curious what your own score is, possibly compared to the scores of the others.

Comment: While perhaps convenient, this feature wouldn't exactly benefit the majority of users, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer that the primaries showed the candidates by vote order,  in a tab (not by default) so that you could order them if you've already voted.  That would mean the tab wouldn't be available by default (to keep people from easily picking the candidates with the most votes and just voting on them.

Comment: I like that idea. Right now I'm doing that with a bookmarklet version of [Sort by vote tally in the election primaries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76438/147015). I agree that this tab should only be available after casting some (maybe on 25% of the candidates?) votes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Won't that encourage people to vote at random to hit 25%?