# Sort moderator nominees by score during primary phase of election after I already voted

Tags: feature-request, election

Currently there is a moderator election on Stack Overflow. For those who vote, the nominees are listed in random order, just to make it fair. This is totally okay to me.

However, when I have voted already, I would like to see the current nominees sorted by their score (just to see who is where, not to influence the process).

Is it possible to make a link or an option to sort, possibly *after* one has voted? (If really afraid of match fixing, the votes could be locked after showing this, but that seems to go a little to far in my opinion)

Comment: Makes total sense, even without a link or option. :)

Comment: In the meantime, install [StackExchange Election: Primary counter](http://stackapps.com/q/4548)

Comment: Related, declined, request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76438/sort-by-vote-tally-in-the-election-primaries

Comment: That is before voting. My request is solely about after voting.

Comment: My [*Stack Exchange, Election Assistant* userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/6692/stack-exchange-election-assistant) sorts by score during and after elections.  (Sorts on the election score, not the user's reputation.)