# Meta questions and votes

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

On *meta* I believe there is a [convention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow) that one is voting for or against the sometimes implied suggestion of a question, rather than the quality of the question itself.   What is the appropriate way to respond to what you consider a good question but a bad idea?

Comment: Comments and answers?  I mean, seriously...

Comment: @Charles, hey, just asking. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: you down vote the question, because as you mention that signifies *I disagree* on Meta. There is nothing forcing you to write an answer or leave a comment, but you can do so if you can explain succintly why you have up or down voted the question; people will then vote on you anser depending on its merits - you may have something in your answer that the OP never thought of which impacts on the viability of the OP's suggestion.