# Can you contest down votes

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to contest a down vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118097/is-there-a-way-to-contest-a-down-vote)

There is a question to which I answered, somebody down voted my answer because he didn't understand the true nature of the question, now I've elaborated in a comment and explained why he was wrong and why my answer was right but it still shows a down vote.

Now I don't think that the down vote is fair as my answer perfectly answers the question and it's just his misinterpretation of the question.

This is the question in question: [Maximum time for rising in a breadmaker](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21977/maximum-time-for-rising-in-a-breadmaker).

Comment: If you can contest downvotes, I humbly request that I can start contesting lazy upvotes to awful answers. Long story short: all downvotes are valid.

Comment: You don't know the person leaving a comment also downvoted. And if you need to put disclaimers or qualifiers in comments, the post is incomplete

Comment: @sixlettervariables Lazy upvotes to awful answers and not to forget especially the mystery 1 upvote on terrible questions.

Answer (score 10):

So then let the community upvote your answer and put it in its rightful place.

A downvote is a trivial thing, stop getting so worked up about it.