# Is this really an answer? I don't think so

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-answer, answer-quality

I was looking for answers to exporting blender projects to Android OpenGL and found one of the most vague and unclear answer on Stack Overflow, which is also the accepted answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285034/android-opengl-blender-is-possible

Clearly, **it does not help** me as I was expecting something more clarified by the user above 4000 reputation points. Are such answers even encouraged?

```
  Question: Android + OpenGl + Blender, is possible?
  Elaborations:Is possible uses Blender (or another tool) to make easy
                 the job in works with android+opengl? Thanks, Celso.

  Answer (Accepted and upvtoed): Yes, it is possible.
```

Comment: explanation for downvote would be amazing. I was only keen on pointing this out because when people post links (as short answers) they don't copy/paste the code it points to. Such a link expires over time and hence later is broken. But the answer above is even worse.

Comment: The answer is not really the problem with that question.  It's closed now, so you should just ask a new (*much* more detailed) question about what you really want to know.

Comment: My answer at least implies why I downvoted. Remember that [downvotes are different on meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow)

Comment: Question is already gone, so I assume it never belonged here in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

The question says, precisely, "Is this possible?" and the answer is "Yes, it is possible." Neither we nor the person who posted that answer have any idea what other information the asker could use. Have they done any Android programming at all? Do they understand what OpenGL is? Do they know Blender at all? Do they understand what a mesh is?

The truth is that if they know what OpenGL is, and what Blender is, and have some idea of how any kind of GUI programming works, let alone Android programming, then they wouldn't even have asked the question, because it really doesn't make any sense without more context. That answer is about the best anyone could do.

Comment: Well the job of a user with 4000 reputation points then is to point out all those things that you have just done. And that's what precisely the next user who answers the question (with merely 1 reputation point) does so. No matter howsoever unclear the question may be, the higher level users should at least make an effort to answer keeping in mind the interests of the users who may be looking for similar answers (for instance, myself today).

Comment: 4000 rep may seem like a lot to you, but I've got ten times that much, and I don't feel like *I* have all the answers, so I don't know why you'd expect so much of him. Furthermore, that person has 4000 rep *now*, but the answer is two years old; they had much less rep when they answered that question!

Comment: @ladiesMan217: It's not really the job of the community to spoon-feed people who can't ask a specific, relevant question.  If the OP wanted to know more than simply "Is it possible," he would have asked.

Comment: Well @RobertHarvey apparently Google or Bing doesn't understand that. The moment i googled "Exporting blender designs to Android" this question showed up. Its not about the community. SO answers are talked about and found useful beyond the scope of its registered users. So when someone is asking "Is It Possible?" then I would at least bother to explain why it is possible or what's missing. Its like comparing a kindergarten True/False question to that of University level. In the latter, you reason as to why it is false.

Answer (score 6):

I just saw that question. I've closed it.  The answer is a symptom.  The problem is that it's a really poor question.  I expect that some 10Kers will go through and delete it, but I have no plans to do so.

Honestly, unless the existence of that question is giving you extreme heartburn, just leave it alone.  There are so many recent questions that need help (or need closing), that dealing with a question from 2 years ago is really not worth anyone's time.

If I had a GTD list of questions to handle right now, and questions to let the community worry about, this would be firmly in the latter bucket.  These types of questions should be handled by the community.  Moderators are needed for current events, not to clean up old questions that no one else is willing to touch.

Comment: I really think this is one that's worthy of an unaccept and deletion. If you look at the answer right below it, it says "Yes, it is possible", but then it goes onto a lot more details. In fact, the more detailed answer was posted first. Even bad questions can sometimes get good answers, and leaving this where it is just leaving a broken window on the site. I downvoted it and  flagged it as not an answer.

Comment: Ok, after *reading* the other answer, I don't feel so strongly about my previous comment. I think the entire thread just needs to go. :)