# Getting attention of a concrete user to a question

Tags: support, questions, users

Sometimes there are some users that you know they can answer your question (for example you're asking a question about Google App Engine and you know there is a user who works for Google, concretely developing GAE)

In such a case, can you explicitly request the attention of that user on your question?

And in that case, how could you do it? The only way I can come up with is to add a comment with `@user`.

Comment: There is no way to ping an individual who has not interacted with your question. Your best bet is to tag it appropriately. Those who follow the tag will see it.

Comment: Thanks for the info @George, I guessed so, but I'd like to be sure, and as I didn't find the answer in the faq section, I asked here... I don't know why you guys downvote questions that easily in meta...

Comment: @MikO We downvote questions that easily on MSO for two reasons: 1) voting here usually means agreement / disagreement with the premise of the question (and not that the question is useful / useless) and 2) MSO reputation is absolutely worthless.

Comment: @Yannis Ahh, I didn't know that, it's an interesting point... but why do you say meta rep is worthless? Is not exactly as worth as SO rep? I mean, it won't make you rich but you can be proud of it ;)

Comment: @MikO Because it doesn't really mean anything because of the strange way voting works on meta (can you tell which side of the fence I'm on)

Comment: @MikO the point to Meta rep being worthless is 2-fold... first on normal child metas (meta.somesite.stackexchange.com), the rep is literally wothless because your Meta rep is derived from your rep on the parent site so voting on that meta doesn't even contribute to your rep.  Second, MSO is special because it serves as the meta site for all of Stack Exchange as well as Stack Overflow.  Here the rep actually can be earned, but it really doesn't do much.  I mean how much is it to be proud that you asked a question about a [meta-tag:bug] that got 100 upvotes.

Comment: @psubsee2003 and others: ok, eventually I've learned a different thing about MSO that I was asking, which is fine, but I have to say I don't agree with this voting system, because the thing that makes the difference between stackexchange and typical forums dissapears this way... The MSO rep system should in my opinion either work as in SO or not exist...

Comment: @MikO Could not agree with you more. If you're interested see this question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow/182028#182028

Comment: @MikO There are plans for MSO to split into Meta Stack Exchange (network wide issues) and... well... MSO (but only for SO). When (if?) that happens, I imagine MSO will become a normal Meta and won't have its own reputation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange *intentionally* doesn't make it easy to get the attention of another individual. If they follow the tag, and are interested in answering your question, they will.

If the user you are interested in contacting has shared any contact details in their profile (e.g. their email or twitter account), they probably wouldn't mind a friendly message about your question (once). If they haven't shared any details, it's probably because they do not wish to be contacted and you should respect that.