# Can I ask if a quote can be beaten?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have received a quote for a spectrometry kit. The kit includes 10+ items, and if I buy the items individually, I may be able to reduce the overall price of the kit. Am I able to ask a question listing the price of each item, in the hope that someone more expert than me knows if the price can be beaten? I believe photo.stackexchange would be a good site to post the question.

Comment: A literal shopping question. No go, man.

Comment: Ouch.. Good luck.

Comment: Whoever is voting to close this as off-topic it's not. It's on-topic on MSO (just not on-topic anywhere else).

Comment: Indeed, just because the answer is no doesn't make the question off topic

Comment: That was totally me, my fault.  With all the off-topic questions in the last few minutes, my trigger finger got itchy.  I'll hang my head in shame now.

Comment: Why 4 downvotes? I didn't post the question - I'm asking if I can post the question.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards. I disagree: I think this *is* off topic here, and would be on topic on meta.photo.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Just because it would be on-topic on another meta doesn't mean it's off-topic on MSO @TRiG... I doubt the answer would be any different either :-).

Comment: @TRiG The answer to this question can apply to any question on any site, even though the OP planed to ask the question on photo.

Comment: @luciano Voting is different on Meta.  Most likely the downvotes are saying this question is not on-topic anywhere.

Comment: @luciano votes are wierd on meta, what the downvotes mean is that you can't ask that question(the shopping one, not this one), not that you're "wrong" for asking the question here (Don't get me started, this happens every time and is completely understandable - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow/182028#182028).

Comment: @RichardTingle thanks for that. As suggested in link, perhaps there should be a separate voting system on meta which provides a measure of a questions suitability on stack exchange. This would save meta newbies like me wondering why they've been down voted, save repeats of this conversation and allow the more normal meaning (unconstructive etc) of downvotes to be used.

Comment: So based on voting, 40% of the people who have voted on this question feel it's okay to ask if the price on a quote can be beaten?

Comment: @LBT No, 40% of people are using a different voting system to you, technically this can't be "voted - against" anyway as its a question not a feature request

Comment: Darn it, at first glance, I thought this was a spam question.

Answer (score 11):

That question would not be on topic on any stack exchange site.

Such a question would be "too localized" as well as "not constructive".

It would be too localized because it's specific to one moment in time; the answers will be constantly changing as prices change.

It's not constructive as there's no one answer, you're looking for lots of answers from different vendors.  Pretty much any question that requires multiple answers instead of being able to be answered once is "not constructive".

See [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more information on the topic of shopping questions.

Comment: Might be worth a couple of moments in a chat room, though.