# How to react when the right answer is given in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, comment-replies

I was wondering, it happened to me a few times that I answered a question in the comments section. This answer finally helped the user to solve his problem, ut as I gave it into the comments section, no answer was accepted, and I didn't receive any reputation.

What am I supposed to do then?  Write an answer and ask the user to accept it?  Or leave it unanswered?

Comment: The question was closed because....?

Comment: If someone else does not answer correctly before *and* the questioner asks you to provide a full answer *and* the question is not a duplicate, go ahead and answer it. You can add additional details or reference links to make it more than a direct translation of your comment.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: The question is this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491269/string-null-pointer-exception  In the comments the user says thanks, you helped me solve my problem, but in fact I didn't explicitly gave him the solution, just a hint. So am I supposed to write an answer for that (as another user did after me..) ? I am just curious about this :)

Comment: @jbihan In that case the comment isn't an answer, it's just helpful information.  It may be possible to write an answer based on that helpful information.  If you (or someone else) wants to take the time to write a full answer based on that information then you are free to do so.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I thought. I just wondered that when I saw that other people were trying to get reputation while the user said he solved his problem...

Comment: I get it, thanks to all ! (finally my question is more useful to me than I thought ;) )

Comment: I usually talk with the OP in my comments, suggesting possibilities or extracting more info.  7/10 times my comments end up solving the issue.  When they do, I usually compile the comments into an answer.  Suggesting others do the same is a good way of dealing with the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a situation without a one-size fits all approach as the solution is going to vary based on the question and the context.

There are probably dozens of other options depending on the exact situation, but you basically have 4 choices:

1. Expand the comment and convert it into a real answer<sup>1</sup>
2. Encourage the OP to provide an answer
3. Do nothing (and/or let someone else provide an answer)
4. Vote to close

<sup>1 - just don't forget to delete your comment when you post your answer</sup>

Which option depends on what your comment actually was, your comfort level with the topic, and what the actually problem was.

- If it was a typo that you pointed out or the OP figured out because of your comment, closing (or flagging) is your best option.
- If you are comfortable with the topic and can provide a real answer to the post, then just expand your comment into an answer.  But don't just copy and paste your comment
- If you aren't comfortable with the topic, don't have the time, or don't care, then just ignore it.  If someone else wants to, then will see your comment helped the OP and they might try to provide a good answer.
- If you don't know what the solution was, then you should encourage the OP to provide his/her own answer.  Nothing is more frustrating than seeing a question describing a problem you are having, seeing the OP solved his problem, and not knowing what the solution actually was.

The important thing to remember is answers are not for the OP, they are for the community (especially future viewers of the question).  I know it is a tough concept for some to grasp, but that is how it was intended for the beginning.  That's why we have standards for questions, so they are of good quality.

That point leads to the general guideline for how to handle these questions.

The purpose of adding the answer is not to give the OP an answer (why does he need an answer, he already has a solution?).  The purpose of adding the answer is to provide an answer to anyone else who happens to see the question in the future.  So it is important the answer (whether added by you, the OP, or someone else) actually provide a real (quality) answer.  Just copy and pasting a comment, or saying "Foo appears to work" (similar to what was done in the example in your comment) doesn't help anyone.  If you think it can be made into an answer, then it should be answered (by someone, not necessarily you).  If not, then it shouldn't and should be closed.

Comment: Speaking of someone taking your answer and expanding on it...  ;o)

Comment: @JohnnyBones I'll admit, the last paragraph was due to your answer.  The rest was mostly expanding my own (now deleted) comment

Comment: It's all good, brother.  I'm just breaking stones.  It's a hobby of mine.  :oD

Comment: I wish I could accept both @JohnnyBones ... but in fact Servy's comments made me doubt and I found this answer clearer

Answer (score -2):

The focus of SO is to answer questions.  That's why the site exists; to provide an answer or to guide the OP to an answer.  Since your comment did just that, your comment should suffice.  I have seen, on a number of my own interactions, where someone [took my answer/comment and expanded on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183989/another-user-used-part-of-my-answer-and-got-points).  In general, it seems like it's best to [not worry about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188022/answer-hijacking-whats-the-proper-course-of-action), but to keep the focus on providing useful information, whether it be a comment or an answer.

Comment: The purpose of the site is *not* to give the OP an answer.  The purpose of the site is to create a repository of knowledge that will be useful to the wider audience of the internet at large.  Having a comment that helps the OP find a solution, but in which the solution isn't posted on the site, does **not** help further that goal.  In fact it harms it.  If someone else has a similar problem and finds this question they may not be able to find their solution based on the limited information in the comments, and shouldn't really need to look through comments in the first place.

Comment: "The purpose of the site is not to give the OP an answer."  Mmmmkay...

Comment: That's a side effect.  A rather beneficial one at times, but it has been stated *often* by the founders of the site that it's *not* the purpose of the site.  It is indeed something that many newer users either don't realize, or have trouble adapting to.