# Why can't questions be deleted by the owner when there is a answer?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, questions, deleted-answers

I have seen a lot of situations where someone posts a question by mistake, find that the answer was obvious, then come back and find that they question has one answer, has lots of downvotes, and is down for closing. Then they try to delete it and they can't because there is a answer. I find this really unfair because they losing reputation to a question that they didn't know was going to get this hated. They can try to flag it for deletion as much as they want but it will never happen. Why did you put up this deletion ban anyways?

Comment: It's pretty hard to accidentally go through all the motions to ask a question on SO. Take more time before posting if that happens to you too much.

Comment: Because the answers are supposed to be helpful for *future* visitors.

Comment: BTW, I read your question as if you're sort of offended by losing a bit of rep for having wasted other peoples time. Not really positive.

Comment: @Mat If you don't have lots of rep in the first place then it is a lot of rep to lose.

Comment: @AndyTechGuy: all the more reason to think before you post, then, don't you think?

Comment: You have six questions and none of them have a negative score. What's the problem? EDIT: I can't even find a downvote. Do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 You are looking at the downvoted question right now.

Comment: @AndyTechGuy - No, it's not: *"I have gotten in **a lot of situations** ... then come back and find that **the question has one answer**, has **lots of downvotes**, and is **down for closing**"*

Comment: I did not mean to start a fight by making this question, I just needed a answer and now I got it.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I changed my mistakes so it relates to everyone, not just me.

Comment: Please stop tagging everything as feature request.

Comment: Ok, I can take a little down votes. And I promice that i will think it through before I ask a question. And I will NEVER post a question like this again.

Comment: @AndyTechGuy this is still being tweaked as it was just posted a few days ago, but you might find this useful [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194703/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture).  The most likely reason, I am guessing, for the downvotes here is "lack of research".  This question has been asked several times before so people are probably saying you should have searched first.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have searched this question to see if it has been asked already and I didn't get anything.

Comment: @AndyTechGuy I'm not saying you didn't just trying to help you understand the downvotes.  Downvotes are far more common on MSO than on SO and depending on the nature of the question, may also be used to express agreement/disagreement with a proposal.  I just noticed you used the "feature-request" tag initially, so people might also have been downvoting your "feature request".  When you are asking questions about "why does something work like this", "support" is a much better tag to use.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am not a whimp, I can take a few downvotes, its just when I don't understand why that I get annoyed

Comment: @AndyTechGuy hence the reason I'm trying to help you understand.  The 2 reasons I mentioned are the best guesses I have, but I think one or both are probably correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a significant problem in the past with people asking questions, getting an answer, and then deleting their question as soon as they got their answer (regardless of whether it got downvotes or not).  Many said that they felt that since they got their answer others shouldn't be spending time reading through it or trying to come up with additional answers.

The problem is that SE sites aren't here to answer one person's question.  They're here to create a repository of knowledge to benefit the internet at large.  The policy you're describing was implemented such that if it is determined that a post contains useful content (with "useful " being defined as an answer with a score of at least +1) then that question should only be deleted through much stricter criteria than just "because the OP clicked a button".

It's not there to punish you, it's there to help others, and to ensure that the person that *did* answer the question doesn't have their useful contributions removed (and the deserved reputation along with it).

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Now can we STOP trying to prove me wrong on my question!

Comment: @AndyTechGuy I'm confused by where the "proving you wrong" is coming from?  If it's related to downvotes on this post, you got 2 (but an upvote to go with it).  If it's about the curiosity about the source of this question, you can't blame people for wondering why you were asking when you didn't have any posts that met the criteria

Comment: @psubsee2003 I changed the question so that it relates to more than just me.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer may be useful to *other* people, since the answer to your question may not be as obvious to future readers as it is to you. Also, just like good questions can have not-so-good answers, not-so-good questions can have good answers. It doesn't make sense to sacrifice the content of the answers and the effort that went into them solely because the OP didn't feel the question was good.

The system also allows you to answer your own question. If you figure out the answer while typing it or immediately after posting it, you can still share that information with the community and provide a resource for someone who sees your question down the road and *doesn't* figure out the answer on their own. If you post a good answer, you've helped the community and may regain some rep in the process.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the things already noted here, well, here's the thing...

Someone spent effort to get you an answer. If you can't delete your question, it's because someone up voted their answer. So, they put in effort and were rewarded for it.

Is it fair to remove that reputation from *them*? (rhetorical question. My answer is a resounding "no!")

Comment: This kinda breaks down for typo questions with trivial answers that get upvotes nevertheless.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question can still be community-deleted; just not unilaterally by the OP.

Answer (score -8):

How do you "not mean to put a question out there"?  I think this function, in general, is meant to make you think before posting.  If this has happened several times, as you've stated, then it leads me to believe you might want to think things through before posting.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  It is, at best, a comment

Comment: -1 for copying your second paragraph *verbatim* from [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195004/218097).

Comment: Re: your edit - not trying to be difficult, but your answer is still not close to what he asked.  He wants to know about deleting answered questions and you are talking about answering your own question and how not to "accidentally" post a question

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think the notion of answering your own question is relevant to *why* the prohibition on self-deletion is in place (that's why I included it in my answer), but I strongly disagree with copying the paragraph *directly* from my answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Do i REALLY need to connect the dots?  I'm working on the assumption that we're dealing with intelligent people, here.

Comment: @JohnnyBones if that's what you think then I am not going to comment anymore.  I just wanted to make sure you were reading the question correctly.  I happen to disagree that self-answering is related to deleting answerewd questions, but that's besides the point

Comment: If you can't come up with your own content, just make this a comment on the question. Don't just copy a significant part of somebody else's answer.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I'm not sure why you keep trying to add the paragraph from my answer in. You've asked [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188022/218097) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183989/218097) about plagiarism, and the responses indicated that copying an entire paragraph isn't accepted. The timestamps *clearly* indicate that you added the paragraph minutes after my answer was posted.

Comment: I totally agree.  Someone, please go downvote ALL of my questions because of this.  :o)