# Requirements for posts on meta-sites

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

I know, that the meta sites (e.g. meta.stackoverflow.com, ell.meta.stackexchange.com, etc) exist for discussing the corresponding main sites (i.e. stackoverflow.com, ell.stackexchange.com, etc).

Still, I have a question: do posts on meta site (I mean, meta of some site, not the global one) are obliged to follow some constraints? If yes, what exactly?

For example, posts on main sites: (1) are required to be questions; (2) should not provoke subjective answers. Is this true for meta? I mean:

1. Is every [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)-tagged post on meta obliged to be formulated as an explicit question? (Can't it be implicit request for discussion of some situation?)
2. Can't post in meta *ask for opinions* about some specific earlier-happened case on the corresponding main site?

Specific example (but I more need clarification in general rather than judgment for the specific example): I this meta-post closed correctly: "[Should we put notices at good (or ok) answers?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/4)"?

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233908/are-poll-style-questions-ever-acceptable-on-meta-sites?rq=1)

Comment: Also very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191773/vote-to-close-as-primarily-opinion-based-on-meta