# Flag history page needs better design

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, flag-history

I think the flagging history page needs more design attention. As of now, I think it's getting a time consuming task to just see what's happening.

Maybe adding a ordering option by "helpful", "declined", "active", "disputed" would be a great addition.

Someone asked how that will benefit. I have flagged posts that are late but still active, some in the middle, some on top. Ordering it (although it still needs better design, I will try to post something) will help to go directly to the flags still active.

That is like it looks now (without hiding the text it is much more obvious but I will not expose the info)

[image: Where's how it is now]

As I'm not a full designer, I will just try to give some idea.

- Perhaps aligning things. I think **right-aligning the status of the flag** would help.
- Colors that make sense with grouping: Spam is the flag subject, but has a background of red. Active is the status of the flag, and has a orange background. **Putting all status with some background color (maybe green for helpful and yellow for disputed)** or removing the spam background color, why it needs that, as the user already flagged?
- The spam is the unique that says "Flagged as" the others put the subject of the flag with a yellow background. **What about putting a "Flagged as (spam, off-topic, not an answer, etc)" to all or none of the status.**
- This should have a reason, but anyway. **Why show my username in MY flags history. Anyway if its to show, why spam flag does not show?**

Comment: I'm not a designer, I'm talking like an end user.

Comment: [Meta doesn't follow same principles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270/212576) as [so]

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I didn't upvote those comments, but I can speculate (since I do agree with the comments)... even with the edit, your feature request is kind of lacking.  I understand you might not be a designer, but as the end user, you can better explain what is lacking from the current interface and how your user experience would benefit from an improvement

Comment: Maybe add "flags" tab like there are tabs for questions, answers, favorites etc.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't get if you are being sarcastic or not. Anyway I thought on that, just thought it has so much to ask.

Comment: @Diego, I just did that, even though you forgot the freehand circles (apologies for the delay, was commuting).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you should be kidding about the freehand circles. Thanks no problem.

Comment: @slhck I get your comment good, not very good :) and so improved the question, so the comment is not rude. But seems that people are not seeming the timestamp, and that was distracting from the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento why sarcastic? I think it deserve the same design like all other lists already in the profile page, not some hidden link that most new users don't know it's even a link. :)