# Propose asking draft questions on other SEs

Tags: feature-request

While authoring a question, I get a list of "similar questions" from the *current* SE site. It would be really nice if it would also be able to say:

> Out ML model think this question has a high chance of being closed on this site for reason `$X`. The model thinks that it would be more on-topic/less-likely-to-be-closed on these other SE sites.

(Well, I think the phrasing would be better using different words, but that's what I expect it would end up actual checking.)

Comment: That would be some heavy algortihm to run I suppose....

Comment: @Luuklag, likely, but from what I understand of modern ML processes, it would be more CPU than dev time: For each site, train a model on the existing corpus of questions to predict the state (open, open w/ accepted answer, closed for `$REASON`). IIRC that's an intern level ML project. Once you have that; run drafts through the local model and where a "favorable outcome" is "too unlikely", check other sites models to get a list of sites that are more likely to give "favorable outcomes". -- The hard part could well end up being getting the draft content to the other site and translating tags!

Comment: Meta² comment: someone down voted this. Okay fine. But what does down voting a *feature request* imply? Does it imply they think implementing this would provide less that zero value? Or just that they think the direct cost would exceed the value? Or that the opportunity cost is too high (there are better things to spend effort on on)? Something else? (Personally I think FRs should only be closed/down-voted for "we'ed be better of sitting on our thumbs doing nothing that implementing that!")

Comment: Downvoting on Meta is different: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites

Comment: @Luuklag: thanks, useful, though that just pushed to question to "what does 'disagree' mean?". Oh well.

Comment: Disagree that your proposed feature is useful at all, or compared against a persons estimation of investment required.

Comment: @Luuklag Okay. Staying off the "wrangling FRs" soapbox is an issue for me but: IMHO "I would get no value from that" should get a neutral response, and the cost of doing something should only impact prioritization of things *after* they are already accepted as "sufficiently desirable" to warrant having. --- That is: "do we want to have this" is a yes/no orthogonal to the cost/benefit question of "can we afford to do it". But that's just, like, my opinion man. :0)