# Is bobby tables a legitimate tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by [stop stupid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/stop-stupid-tags), I want to ask is "[bobby-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bobby-tables)" a legitimate tag? (For those who don't know: Bobby tables is from an XKCD comic about SQL injection called "Exploits of a Mom")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I would say **no**.

Even though the two questions tagged with it are regarding problems that the cartoon is referring to, the tag is not helpful.

No one looking for the problems described in the questions will ever search for the tag 'bobby-tables', and anyone searching for the tag 'bobby-tables' isn't looking for help on any problems similar to the questions that have the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I took care of those two.

A user named [Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) added them. Going for a taxonomist, perhaps? But he hasn't used them since those two, and they were almost 2 months ago, so perhaps he thought better of using that as a tag?

Comment: No problem. +15

Comment: I think the tag's older than that. I noticed the tag in August http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/12746#12746

Comment: Hrm. Someone else must have cleaned that up. Maybe he **was** going for taxonomist. And you know what? He got it ... So yeah, that was probably why he was doing it. I'm going to go back and tag everything I can in Meta with the-txi (I think I created it) so I can get it, too! (I keed, I keed!)

Comment: Life's a lot more pleasant if you don't assign motivations to people.  I've never given a crap about badges.  I probably just tagged things "bobby-tables" until I realized there was one already for "sql-injection", which I now apply regularly.