# Is there an Canonical SQL Injection page?

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

Is there a canonical SQL injection page that I can point people towards when they post a question with an SQL injection vulnerability?  Is it polite to do this.  Sometimes, I know it's just an example, and that it isn't real code so it's OK if it has SQL injection vulnerabilities. However, when it's a new user, with low rep asking a very simple question, I find it very hard not to try and teach them about the dangers of SQL Injection.  Is there a specific Stackoverflow question I can point them to? Or is there some other page on the internet that better explains the problem. and can help them fix it.

Comment: Whenever you encounter somebody smoking a cigarette, do you also find it very hard not to try to teach them about the dangers of cigarette smoking?

Comment: @Gabe: There's a *big* difference. If the smoke of the cigarette blown into the wrong direction could expose millions of banking accounts, then yes, I'd tell them that they should quit smoking. Smoking is more like `Global Variables`.

Comment: Does the question belong to SO?

Comment: I honestly think the SO engine could/should parse code snippets in PHP+mysql tagged questions and autolink to some canonical question if it contains both `mysql_query` and `$_GET`/ `$_POST` / `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, xkcd's [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is standard.  It must be one of the most frequently linked pages at SO.

Comment: While funny, it doesn't really get the point across to somebody who is not familiar with the problem.  Also, it doesn't really explain how it can be fixed.

Comment: On the contrary, a light-weight version of "you are doing something really dumb" is much more effective.  Somebody that can't take that hint (they made a *cartoon* about it!) and research this problem by himself cannot be helped.  Link to a dup if you have to.

Comment: Some people occasionally made it into a tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32108/is-bobby-tables-a-legitimate-tag

Comment: Don't forget to mention [that this comic strip got his own homepage](http://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: @Bobby: Are you named after Robert drop tables?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Not that I know of, but my name is Robert, though.

Answer (score 6):

You could author the [sql-injection](/questions/tagged/sql-injection) tag [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info) and point people towards that.

Answer (score 5):

Why, uh, [here's a nice answer to a sql injection question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain/332367#332367/1228) that you could link to.  Over and over.  Pretty please.

Comment: Interesting - the question had been viewed 7.5 Ktimes, but there was code that hadn't been highlighted.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: All of the sql code is in code blocks.  As for why it hasn't been colored properly I can't quite tell...  brb sandbox.

Comment: @Will - sorry, I was referring to one of the answers not having code highlighted.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Sql isn't getting prettified...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90521/prettify-hates-sql-or-how-do-i-get-prettify-to-properly-handle-sql

Comment: There are quite a few [sql-injection] questions that don't have a language specified, so I just set the default highlighting on the tag to lang-sql.

Comment: @mmyers: Doesn't appear to be working for my *incredibly awesome answer*

Comment: No? [This is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg7Bk.png).

Comment: @mmyers: I *swear* it wasn't doing it when I looked at it earlier.  Perhaps cache?

Answer (score 3):

Point them to OWASP, they have good ressources that explains well the security problem, what to do and what not to do. It is one of the rare places that you are sure to find quality information about security problem.

Pages they have about SQL Injection :

[SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
[Guide to SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection)
[SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
[Reviewing Code for SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Code_for_SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the [Wikipedia page on SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because it provides an adequate description of the problem, provides an overview of the solution, and lists notable hacks where it was a factor.

It's also rather long, so it might not actually be *read*.

Comment: perhaps this is an argument for a canonical question/answer pair here that *sumarrizes* this information in a more scannable way? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Answer (score 1):

Someone needs to do a rant on the subject equal to the [Cthulhu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on regular expressions and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This answer seems like a reasonable bet for PHP + MySQL, which I'd bet is the worst offender:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I've just edited in a link to the bobby tables question to give context.

Answer (score 0):

I learned about it at [sqlzoo.net/hack.](http://sqlzoo.net/hack/)