# Prettify hates sql, or How do I get Prettify to Properly Handle SQL?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

None of these appear to be working... Edit to see the ways and means it fails.

language: lang-sql, no indent on Prettify comment

Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"

language: sql, no indent on Prettify comment

Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"

language: lang-sql, Prettify comment indented

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

language: sql, Prettify comment indented

```
<!-- language: sql -->
Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

Comment: Today I learned you can put a language comment in code as a hint for Prettify.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Congrats.  How do you do this?

Comment: Ahhhhh...about that. I meant "today I learned from **Will don't give a**'s question on Meta, where he posted a code sample." Meaning your code above. Does it work for, say, C# at least?

Comment: @Justin: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify

Comment: related - [Unbalanced blank lines after inline HTML comments might break formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74754)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The language comment shouldn't be indented and you should put a blank line between the comment and the code

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

This should yield

```sql
Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

The highlight is pretty subtle though.

Comment: True. Or, I guess more precisely one could say: Markdown code blocks need a blank line before and after it to distinguish it from other Markdown parts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learned something new today, and apparently this does work for C#.

As you can see, [SQL is included in the official language list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) So it *should* work. One thing that might come into play is that the tagging format is a little tricky, and took me a couple of tries to get right. Your Prettify comment should be on its own line, **but not indented.** Then your (indented) code goes two lines below it. If you look at the source code of Jeff's answer in the link above, you can see how to do it.

If you've already tried that and it didn't work, then you've got yourself a bug.

Test:

```sql
Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

Source:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

**Update:** Looks like it works.