# Moderation team feedback needed on tag specificity: [xpath] vs the world

Tags: support, tags, moderators

See previous topic: [What did happen with “xpathengines” and “xqueryengines” tags, and why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-did-happen-with-xpathengines-and-xqueryengines-tags-and-why)

tl;dr:

> An unknown moderator performed two tag merges.  A few users frequenting the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) tag objected.  Other moderators and other SO users tried to help explain the decision to those users.
>
> The primary argument in favor of the merge is that having a tag *just* for *all* implementations of xpath/xquery reduces the visibility of those questions.  Questions placed under the tag also had *very little to no relationship* to each other.  The tag did not help categorize the questions in a way that would assist question askers.
>
> The primary argument against the merge seemed to be that the objecting users simply don't want questions in the `xpath`/`xquery` tags that aren't completely dedicated solely to those tags.  This seems to be an argument about semantic purity.

While using the 10k tools page, I noticed some new xpath-related tags spring into existence.  It seems that some questions that were previously tagged `xpath` are now having that tag *removed* and replaced with [xpath-implementation](/questions/tagged/xpath-implementation).  Some other xpath-related questions are being un-`xpath`'d and being given other xpath-related-but-not-`xpath` tags, like [xpath-2.0-implementations](/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0-implementations) (e: [only question retagged by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802895/does-jdk-6-support-all-features-of-xpath-2-0)) and [zend-framework-xpath](/questions/tagged/zend-framework-xpath) (which I have removed from the [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916984/xpath-query-to-get-html-nodes-with-multiple-classes-using-php-zend-dom-query) that was retagged, in favor of tagging that will make the question findable by Zend Framework people).

**This tag replacement is effectively the same thing that was previously undone by the moderation team**. It's clear and obvious that `xpath-implementation` and `xpath-2.0-implementations` tags are simple copies of the previous `-engines` tag.

I'd like to get a clear message from the moderation team in regard to:

1. whether or not these new horribly-inspecific tags should exist, and
2. whether or not xpath/xquery-*related* questions should be removed from the vanilla tags *in favor* of the specific tags

It's my opinion that these new tags should not exist, and xpath/xquery-*related* questions should not be purged from the vanilla tags.  I'm more than willing to simply go through and revert the retags, but I expect that doing so without some diamond backing is going to result in an even larger drama explosion/trainwreck than the creation of this question will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Tags are not hierarchical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so). You can set up wildcard searches to produce questions across similar tags... But this is more useful as a way to search/watch questions in related tags: making wildcards necessary to find all questions that fall in the domain of a single tag defeats the purpose of *having* that tag.

But set ops work just fine for limiting yourself to a subset of questions in a given tag: want all XPath questions that involve Java? [No problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath+java) Hate Java? And C#? Loathe PHP and despise JavaScript? [Hey, you can exclude those just as easily!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath+-java+-c#+-php+-javascript)

What you *can't* do is remove a relevant tag from all the questions you don't want to see. If you see this happening again, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Does this answer speak for the moderator team?  I'm sure that you're going to be *perceived* as biased by certain other involved parties, so stating that the moderation team backs your answer is probably going to be important.

Comment: @Charles: I fully agree with Shog9's interpretation.  All of the new tags you described above *are too specific.*

Comment: In this particular instance, I'm speaking for SE Inc., reiterating what was already discussed in previous threads (both the one you linked to [and others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/congratulations-eric-lippert-for-finally-winning-the-c-language-badge)).