# Interesting Thought - Tag Wikis for Combinations of Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526363/76337) a question on exception handling instead of just posting the link to the [exception-handling](/questions/tagged/exception-handling) tag wiki. One of the reasons is that the [exception-handling](/questions/tagged/exception-handling) tag is not specific to .NET, and both the question, and my answer, were specific to .NET.

If the tag had been .net-exception-handling, then I would have edited the tag wiki to include links to some great Stack Overflow questions and answers on exception handling. There are many answers on the site better than mine. I would also have added links to the .NET Framework Design Guidelines sections on exceptions and exception handling.

It just struck me that we should be able to create a tag wiki for the *combination* of tags [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)[exception-handling](/questions/tagged/exception-handling). Such a tag wiki would be a perfect place for such a set of links, making it easier for me to avoid duplicate answers to duplicate questions on exception handling in .NET.

Comment: Perhaps we *should* just create the `[.net-exception-handling]` tag. Since why would you ever go looking for questions about exception handling in any language under the sun? Then you could create the tag wiki and retag questions, without adding another layer of complexity to a system that already confuddles lots of users.

Comment: I could see using the combined tag, but then, should we retag all [tag:.net][tag:exception-handling] questions? Even just to add the new tag when there's room?

Comment: BTW, if retag is the answer, then either someone other than I will do the retagging, or it will wait for Jeff to be out: I nearly got suspended by Jeff for creating the "c#-language" tag. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/congratulations-eric-lippert-for-finally-winning-the-c-language-badge

Comment: @cody: I've always assumed [tag:exception-handling] was intended to be used in conjunction with [tag:c++] or [tag:c#] or [tag:python] to find questions about exception handling in your languages of choice.

Comment: @sarnold: Probably, that's currently the *only* way it's useful. But I don't see why that scenario is any better than having separate tags for exception handling regarding those languages, e.g. `[c++-exception-handling]` or `[python-exception-handling]`.

Answer (score 2):

I can almost see where you're going with this; at least, the specific example you gave makes sense. But we have [876 pages of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=876&tab=popular). [After 300 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=876&tab=popular) the tag wikis are looking pretty thin.

If we allow tag wikis on *combinations of tags*, that'll be orders of magnitudes more tag wikis that could or should be maintained. I like that tag wikis take a bit of effort to create and maintain; they're "more permanent" than questions or answers, but "out of the way" enough that oddball content might sit there for months or years before being noticed. If we exponentially increase the amount of wikis that are possible I think curating them will be impossible. *You* might do a good job curating your three or four favorites but I don't see that scaling well to the 826^2 pages of tag combinations.

<sub>Yes, someone would have to put effort into creating them -- they wouldn't be magically called into being -- but we've all seen suggested edits approved without sufficient scrutiny.</sub>