# Best way to mass-apply a new tag to old questions

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, tag-creation

I am now in the following situation for the third time:

I have detected a need for a new tag and I am sure about this (e.g., as I have successfully proposed this on the respective site meta) and there already is a fair amount of questions to which this tag should be applied.

**What is the best practice as to mass-applying this tag to old questions?** My main concern is that doing all of this at once may be a severe disruption on sites with lower activity, as all of these questions get bumped.

While [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35774/255554) has been asked before, this was some time ago and applied to Stack Overflow, whose activity is not on a totally different scale than the sites I am worrying about.

Comment: Though my question is of a general nature, the tag proposed by me [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1148/7734) may serve as an example, if required.

Comment: Maybe this should be a `feature-request` for a "retagging shouldn't bump" feature.

Comment: @MrLister: [This has been done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241/255554), sort of.