# Tags submission should include stop words

Tags: feature-request, tags, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement a Tag Black List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

The tag submission algorithm should include a stop-word implementation that filters out common words such as "and", "or", "but", "the", etc.  These words make horrible tags and only make more clean up work necessary (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585304/array-and-linked-list), check edit history).  This could be extended to filter out other unwanted tags as suggested in the related question.

Also, we should probably retag `and` as `logical-and`, `bitwise-and`, etc. as necessary.

See here for a list of questions tagged [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/and) on SO, by my count only 4 of 10 are referring to an `and` operation. **EDIT**: I've cleaned up most of these, but haven't done any retagging to "logical-*" pending whether the stop-words are officially filtered.

Related to: [Stop stupid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/stop-stupid-tags)

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list (status-planned)

Comment: @Jon - SO search fails me again, although, that issue seems to be more inline with the related question that I referenced, not the "common" words.  Common words that make bad tags should be included.  I'll add my "question" there as an "answer".